# Unable to filter the data with json key values in mysql

Tags: mysql

The data storing in a field --view field name custom_field

```
[{"age":"18,19,20","id":569},{"apple1":"bd,sql","id":571}]
```

filtering the data with this query is working fine

```
select * 
from abc.leads_details 
where owner_id=11796 
    and JSON_SEARCH(custom_field, 'all', '18,19,20', NULL, '$[*]."age"') is  not null ;
```

but if I filter with age key value is 20 then  i will not fetch the record

```
select * 
from abc.leads_details 
where owner_id=11796 
    and JSON_SEARCH(custom_field, 'all', '20', NULL, '$[*]."age"') is  not null ;
```

i want to filter with the comma separted values

```
select * 
from abc.leads_details 
where owner_id=11796 
    and JSON_SEARCH(custom_field, 'all', '20,19', NULL, '$[*]."age"') is  not null ;
```

Comment: Why are you storing a comma-separated value instead of a JSON array `[18,19,20]`? Isn't that one one of the points of using JSON?

Comment: You'll need to do something involving the `FIND_IN_SET()` function, just like you would if you had a comma-separated value outside JSON.

Comment: You want to search CSV in CSV? If you need to search "at least one value is present" then the simplest way is to convert CSV to JSON array and use JSON_OVERLAPS. But if you need "all values are present" then you must parse one of CSVs (the argument parsing seems to be more simple) to separate values, search for each of them and count the amount of positive searching results comparing them with total values amount.